# Inline-block HTML5/CSS3 COLUMNS

Tags: html, css

I want the css for those 3 articles (`.leftContent`, `.middleContent` and `.rightContent`) to act like they are `inline-block` columns... the body is 70% width.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J795Q/)

Comment: Act like? What you do mean.

Comment: i just want them as inline-block columns.. dunno how to explain you better. i want all them inline

Comment: or [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/J795Q/2/) ? Just changed the CSS values to use `.` instead of `,`.

Comment: yeah ty mate. just like that? wow ahah

Comment: You were using commas as Sirko points out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.` instead of `,` to make width a float value:

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/J795Q/4/)

You can also use `display:table-cell`:

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/J795Q/5/)

Also, as you are using the same CSS properties for the same elements, you can use something like this :

```
article {
   display: inline-block;
   width:23.33%; 
}
```

To apply the same CSS properties to all `article`s.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/J795Q/7/)